# simple LINQ / Lambda query not compiling

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to linq and am having a real hard time grasping it.

My code is an linq that is supposed to filter all students that are born prior to 1984 from  a class Allstudents. Sorry about the snippets, my first time here.

```
private void Linq2()
    {
        Header("Linq2");

                    var Student = from B in TestData.AllStudents
                      where TestData.AllStudents.Where(x => x.Birthday.Year > 1984)
                      select B;

    }



 public static List<Student> AllStudents
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<Student>
                {
                    new Student {Id=1, FirstName="Lisa", Birthday=new DateTime(1980, 1, 1), FavoriteSubject="Geography", NumberOfOwnedBooks=10},
                    new Student {Id=2, FirstName="Ali", Birthday=new DateTime(1985, 2, 2), FavoriteSubject="Geography", NumberOfOwnedBooks=10},
                    new Student {Id=4, FirstName="George", Birthday=new DateTime(1960, 3, 3), FavoriteSubject="Mathematics", NumberOfOwnedBooks=20},
                    new Student {Id=5, FirstName="Susan", Birthday = new DateTime(1960, 3, 3), FavoriteSubject = "Mathematics", NumberOfOwnedBooks = 30 },
                    new Student {Id=3, FirstName="Britney", Birthday=new DateTime(1980, 1, 1), FavoriteSubject="Mathematics", NumberOfOwnedBooks=40},
                };
            }
        }
```

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'

Error   CS1662  Cannot convert query expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
edited for code snippets

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing lambda query syntax in the query expression syntax, actually the alias which you created in first line (`from B in TestData.AllStudents`) in that the `B` needs to be used down in where clause like `where B.Birthday.Year > 1984` as you wrote in `select` part:

```
var Students = from B in TestData.AllStudents
                      where B.Birthday.Year > 1984
                      select B;
```

and If you want to use lambda expression version then it should be :

```
var Students = TestData.AllStudents.Where(x => x.Birthday.Year > 1984);
```

Comment: Thank you Ehsan for the explanation, that did it

Answer (score 2):

One can only guess since you don't post the actual compile error, but that `TestData.AllStudents.Where(x => x.Birthday.Year > 1984)` is definitely wrong. Just write:

```
var students = from B in TestData.AllStudents
               where B.Birthday.Year > 1984
               select B;
```

It's a good idea to use descriptive names for all variables:

```
var students = from student in TestData.AllStudents
               where student.Birthday.Year > 1984
               select student;
```

If you don't want to use the query format, you can use:

```
var students=TestData.AllStudents
                     .Where(student=>student.Birthday.Year > 1984);
```

The result is the same in all case: an `IEnumerable<Student>` that you can iterate over, or convert to a list with [ToList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) or array with [ToArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx) etc

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis, that did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var stds = dbContext.AllStudents.Where(m=>m.Birthday.Year>1984);
return stds.ToList();
```